# How do I use bearer token to navigate to a secured page in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, jwt

I'm trying to learn JWT authentication in ASP.NET Core and have been following some tutorials but have come to a roadblock. What I am trying to do is to get the user to go to a login page and once correct credentials are entered, generate an access_token and then use this token to access the secured page (MVC Action method).

I am able to generate the token and in Postman I am able to access the secured page because I can set the bearer token manually in it once I generate it. My problem is once I'm in the app. I don't know how to set the bearer token so I can navigate to the secured page.

In my login page, I have an Ajax call that does the login and in the success response, I am returning the access_token:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Account/Login",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(loginData),
})
.done((response) => {
    if (response.Success) {
        // access token available here
        window.location.href = response.ReturnUrl;
    }
    else {
        //...
    }
})
```

But I am stuck here, I don't know how I can use the access_token to navigate to the secured page. What I am trying to do is after correct login, go to the secured page but this time with the access_token so I can access it.

Where do I do this? How do I do it correctly?

Comment: If you are navigating around to different pages, it sounds like you need cookie authentication instead? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: @Jack: Can I not use JWT for page navigations?

Comment: yes, but you will need a combindation of JWT, and the storage of the token within a cookie, that token can then be used until it expires, and the need for another token.